# How can i print a pipe delimiter in a QR barcode using ZPL-ii language?

Tags: zpl-ii

I am trying to print a pipe in a QR barcode using ZPL code to a GX420D but can't seem to get the correct outcome. I tried using the ^FH and adding the _7c for a pipe but when i print the barcode and read it with a scanner it prints a tilda instead?? The code i have written is as below, the @labno etc are tokens that we use to print info from the system

```
~CC$
$XA
$SZ2
$PW450
$JMA $JZY
$A0N,20,20
$FO150,30$FDTest text $FS
$FO30,30
$BQ,2,3,
$FDQA,@labno| @slcod| @slnum| @spsuf| @snfni$FS
$FO20,20
$XZ
```

the following shows this when scanned with a barcode scanner

```
~ @labno~ @slcod~ @slnum~ @spsuf~ @snfni
```

I just want to be able to add a pipe into the QR that I want to print, is this possible?

Comment: Is the keyboard language of the scanner set to English?

Comment: Yes as far as i'm aware, it decodes with no problems

Comment: Have you tried another scanner or with a smartphone app?